# How to run an ASP.NET web page on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono

I have been trying to follow this tutorial to the letter:

http://library.linode.com/frameworks/mod-mono/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Installed Ubuntu server and successfully run it
2. I can access and HTML page perfectly fine on the server
3. I installed MONO on Ubuntu server
4. I created /srv/www/example.org/public_html & logs
5. I added the link to the /ect/apache2/sites-available/example.org
6. I added my ASP.NET file to /srv/www/example.org/public_html/test.aspx
7. I added a config file: /srv/www/example.org/public_html/test.aspx
8. I then reloaded apache and went to the web page

I came to a site that listed the available files.  I saw web.config and test.aspx.  When I click on test.aspx it shows the code instead of the ASP web page.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the `xsp2` server? `XSP server is a sample server that hosts the ASP.NET runtime in a
minimalistic HTTP server`.

Comment: This post contains simple steps http://codenuggets.com/2012/05/23/installing-asp-net-on-ubuntu-with-mod_mono-autoconfig/

Answer (score 5):

Basically, Microsoft did just about everything possible to ensure that you need to run ASP.Net on a Microsoft server.

Nevertheless, you *should* be able to run at least *some* .aspx scripts on an Apache server, using mod_mono.

Q: Are you sure you installed the mod_mono plugin correctly?

Q: Are you sure you configured Apache to recognize the mod_mono plugin, and invoke it for .aspx files?

Here are a couple of other links that might help you:

- http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono

Note in particular the "troubleshooting" tips at the bottom of the Ubuntu link.